# How to combine and then branch in MonadPlus/Alternative

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor, monadplus

I recently wrote

```hs
do
  e <- (Left <$> m) <|> (Right <$> n)
  more actions
  case e of
    Left x -> ...
    Right y -> ...
```

This seems awkward. I know that `protolude` (and some other packages) define

```hs
-- Called eitherP in parser combinator libraries
eitherA :: Alternative f => f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
```

But even with that, it all feels a bit manual. Is there some nice pattern I haven't seen for tightening it up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just noticed that OP expressed this same idea [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840743/how-to-combine-and-then-branch-in-monadplus-alternative#comment125237857_70841487).  I'm going to post my thoughts anyway.

---

Coyoneda is a neat trick, but it's a little overkill for this particular problem.  I think all you need is regular old continuations.

Let's name those `...`s:

```hs
do
  e <- (Left <$> m) <|> (Right <$> n)
  more actions
  case e of
    Left x -> fx x
    Right y -> fy y
```

Then, we could instead have written this as:

```hs
do
  e <- (fx <$> m) <|> (fy <$> n)
  more actions
  e
```

This is slightly subtle — it's important to use `<$>` there even though it looks like you might want to use `=<<` so that the result of the first line is actually a monadic action to be performed later rather than something that gets performed right away.

Comment: Nice solution, it reminds me of the "return a command" trick which also uses nested actions: https://www.haskellforall.com/2021/10/the-return-command-trick.html

Comment: There is a difference these two code snippets, though: in the first one, `fx` can cleanly mention variables bound by `more actions`.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're definitely right.  It's possible to let `fx :: TypeOfM -> More -> Types -> m ()` and similarly for `fy`.  Then, the last line would be `e p q` or something similar.  If there are a lot of variables bound in `more actions`, this becomes ugly fast, but for just one or two, it can work out nicely.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that's true; at some point my original solution probably starts to look good. But in me original context, there were no variables bound.

Answer (score 10):

This is *way* overthinking the question, but...

In your code, the types of each branch of the `Either` might be distinct, but they don't escape the do-block, because they are "erased" by the `Left` and `Right` continuations.

That looks a bit like an existential type. Perhaps we could declare a type which packed the initial action along with its continuation, and give that type an `Alternative` instance.

Actually, we don't have to declare it, because such a type already exists in Hackage: it's [`Coyoneda`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2.3/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html#t:Coyoneda) from [kan-extensions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions).

```
data Coyoneda f a where       
    Coyoneda :: (b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a
```

Which has the useful instances

```
Alternative f => Alternative (Coyoneda f)
MonadPlus f => MonadPlus (Coyoneda f)
```

In our case the "return value" will be itself a monadic action `m`, so we want to deal with values of type `Coyoneda m (m a)` where `m a` is the type of the overall do-block.

Knowing all that, we can define the following function:

```
sandwich :: (Foldable f, MonadPlus m, Monad m) 
         => m x 
         -> f (Coyoneda m (m a)) 
         -> m a
sandwich more = join . lowerCoyoneda . hoistCoyoneda (<* more) . asum
```

Reimplementing the original example:

```
sandwich more [Coyoneda m xCont, Coyoneda n yCont]
```

Comment: I kind of like it! It also seems to suggest a more elementary approach, which I think I like even more: `do { final <- (m <&> xCont) <|> (n <&> yCont); more; actions; final }`

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, `Coyoneda` is overkill here. Keeping the initial action and the continuation separate using `Coyoneda` works, but nesting them is simpler and you don't need any extra types.

Comment: This actually looks really cool – at last an application of Yoneda reduction that serves a clear purpose and isn't just “trivial yet inscrutable”! Does this have a good category-theory explanation? `Alternative`/`MonadPlus` always seem a bit on the shadier side of Haskell's functor hierarchy.

Comment: @leftaroundabout IIRC, another use of `Coyoneda` is to make functors out of types like `IORef` that don't have the instance, by "stashing" the fmappings in the function component of `Coyoneda`. https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5v33qk/forall_a_ioref_a_lens_a_b_is_a_useful_type_does/ddyxp6x/

Comment: @leftaroundabout, there are some pretty cool things you can do with (Co)Yoneda and similar types in combination with generic traversals. Sadly I couldn't convince recent GHCs to optimize those well, but that's not their fault. (Join points vs. inlining. *Sigh*)

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use `hoistCoyoneda` here even if you use `Coyoneda`. You can lower first, at which point you're back on the elementary solution track.

Answer (score 6):

You could perhaps do it like this:

```
do
  let acts = do more actions
  (do x <- m; acts; ...) <|> (do y <- n; acts; ...)
```

I don't know if that looks better to you.

(Of course this doesn't work out nicely if those `more actions` bind many variables)

Comment: That's only equivalent for instances satisfying left distribution, I believe, since it'll reserve judgement to see if the intermediate actions fail.

Comment: Could be good in those cases, but my (foolishly unspoken) context was left catch.